# Qualtrics Preview Email

Tags: preview, qualtrics

I am looking to send out my survey via email to a set list of contacts but would like to see it before it sends out.  I see that there is a "Send Preview Email" option.

Before I select this option, I'm wondering who that will send to and how?  I assume it will send to the "Reply-to" email listed... However, I have some piped text (like External Data Reference) in the email and the reply-to email will not have that information.

I just want to be sure it looks like what I want it to before I send it out.

Comment: Test it. Send it to yourself. Please see the [How to Ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) page for future reference.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you click "Send Preview Email" you will be prompted for an email address however your piped text will not be sent through using this option ( the values will appear blank).

Your best option is to create a panel with just your email address and add the embedded data fields that you need for the email. Now you can just send the survey normally to that panel that just has you on it.

There is also a support team who you can ask about product functionality at support@qualtrics.com for faster assistance.